# kotlin android action bar title

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar

The below functions in MainActivity, App name is Qpon. 
The app runs well, only the Action bar title of the first page has an issue. It suppose to show "fff" for the bar title, but it shows App Name "Qpon" when the app started.
But it shows properly when I go to other fragment and come back to the first fragment.

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_qpon -> {
                //message.setText(R.string.title_qpon)
                actionBarIcon(R.drawable.ic_title_black)
                createQponFragment()

                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_me-> {
                //message.setText(R.string.title_me)
                actionBarIcon(R.drawable.logged)
                createMeFragment()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_tool -> {
                //message.setText(R.string.title_tool)
                actionBarIcon(R.drawable.logged)
                createToolFragment()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_tutorial -> {
                //message.setText(R.string.title_tutorial)
                actionBarIcon(R.drawable.tutorial)
                createTutorialFragment()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)

        actionBarIcon(R.drawable.ic_title_black)

        createQponFragment()
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }


    fun getCurrentNumber():String {
        var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val cUser = mAuth?.currentUser
        val userPhone = cUser?.phoneNumber
        if (userPhone != null) {
            return userPhone.toString()
        }
        else { return "" }
    }

    fun actionBarIcon(imageName:Int) {

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
        my_toolbar.setLogo(imageName)

        if (imageName == R.drawable.ic_title_black) my_toolbar.setTitle("fff")
        if (imageName == R.drawable.logged) my_toolbar.setTitle(getCurrentNumber())
        if (imageName == R.drawable.tutorial) my_toolbar.setTitle("Tutorial")
    }
```

The app start image
[image]

Came back from other fragment
[image]

Comment: Might be related to `createQponFragment()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fun actionBarIcon(imageName:Int) {

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
        my_toolbar.setLogo(imageName)

/* 
What is to be done to solve the issue:-
Below code is setting up title to fff if only the condition is met. but there you have not set any title if condition is not met so by default it is picking up app name.
So, give a default value when activity is visible. Either provide title to toolbar in layout or use  

// Set toolbar title/app title
        my_toolbar!!.title = "fff"
 */

        if (imageName == R.drawable.ic_title_black) my_toolbar.setTitle("fff")
        if (imageName == R.drawable.logged) my_toolbar.setTitle(getCurrentNumber())
        if (imageName == R.drawable.tutorial) my_toolbar.setTitle("Tutorial")
    }
```

You can check the comment in code or refer below link for example
Visit https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/02/android-kotlin-toolbar-example.html